# Upon exceeding maximum size new log file is not generated

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

I have set the maximum file size as 100Kb. But the on exceeding the size, no new log file is generated. Instead the file size goes on increasing. If I restart the server, new log file is generated. Can someone please tell me that is this the correct scenario or is it because of any setting issue?

my log4j settings is as below.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/logs/sample.log
log4j.appender.file.Append = true
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 100KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: I would like to add an observation also. Consider there are two files initially, sample.log and sample.log.1
when sample.log reaches more than 100KB, sample.log.1 will be renamed to sample.log.2 and sample.log remains same.

when sample.log reaches more than 200KB, sample.log.2 will be renamed to sample.log.3 and sample.log remains same.

in the same way when it reaches more than 600KB, sample.log.5 will get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in `rollOver()` method in `RollingFileAppender.java`, renaming of the current log file is failing.

```
renameSucceeded = file.renameTo(target);
```

Here file.renameTo(target); returns false. To solve this, override the method and add custom code to fix the issue. One way to do is add the below code after the above statement.

```
if(!renameSucceeded)                                //custom code begins
      {                                                 
         try 
         {
            FileUtils.copyFile(file, target);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            bw.write("");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            renameSucceeded = true;
        } 
         catch (IOException e) {
             renameSucceeded = false;
        }
      }
```